Is there any licensing model details for Blueprint Migration Assistance tool to migrate UiPath RPA processing to Power Automate Desktop
We have requirement to migrate UiPath RPA processing to Power Automate Desktop. We want to use the Blueprint migration assistance for the same. Do anyone have any idea on the licensing model of the Blueprint tool ?
Please guide me on this.
Thanks in advance!
